# indexing for a symbolic function

Tags: matlab

I want to define f0(x), f1(x) and ... symbolically by using a loop and then differentiate them with respect to x, but I can't.
Does anyone know how?

I tried this but don't think this is right

```
for i=0:n
    F(i+1)=sym(strcat('f(x)',num2str(i)));
end
```

Comment: Use a cell array?

Comment: @CrisLuengo   it doesn't matter. I just want to define them by using a loop.

Comment: Just do it...?  Matlab supports symbolic vector with the default `sym` function.